# Printing random elements of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, output

I have written a program that has M*N elements where variables M and N are entered by the user. The program prints the elements in an M x N table and assigns random values to each element. When I try compiling the program, two errors keep popping up. The first says that there is a implicit declaration of function "PopulateRandom" in line 12. The second message says that there is a missing expression expected before "int" in line 25.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Prints elements of array in a M x N table
int PrintArray2D(int M, int N){
    int array[M*N], row, column, i;

    while(row <= M && column <= N){
    for(row = 0; row <= M; row++){
        for(column = 0; column <= N; column++){
            array[i] = PopulateRandom(array[M * N]);
            printf("%d", array[i]);
            if(column == 4){
                break;
            }
        }
        column = 0;
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return array[i];
}

//Assigns elements of the array "array" random values
int PopulateRandom(int array[int M * int N]){
    int i;

    while(i = 0; i < M*N; i++){
    array[i] = rand() % (M*N);
    }
    return array[i];
}

int main(void){
    int option, M, N;

    printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
    printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    while(option != 0){
    switch(option){
        case 1: if(option == 1){
                printf("Enter two numbers M and N: ");                          
                scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);
                PrintArray2D(M, N);
        }
        case 0: if(option == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
    printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    }
}
```

Comment: `PopulateRandom` has no function prototype (forward reference), therefore the compiler can only make assumptions about its argument and return types.

Comment: ... and `array[int M...` is not correct. Did you mean `int PopulateRandom(int array[M * N])`?

Comment: Sorry, which line number are you refering too?

Comment: @Shoaib Ahmed  Where is there the 2D array?:)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining about the implicit declaration of function `PopulateRandom` because you are calling it before declaring/defining it before. Simply define `PopulateRandom` before calling it in `PrintArray2D`.
Regarding that, you may find [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) interesting.
The second problem may be caused by this line of code :

```
while(i = 0; i < M*N; i++)
```

If you want to concatenate more conditions you should use either logical and (&&) *or/and* logical or (||).

The way you used this while loop make that's not the right one.
The while loop is not the for-loop, the syntax is different.

for-loop syntax :

```
for (init; condition; increment)
```

While-loop syntax :

```
while (cond1 && cond2 || cond3)
```

Other problem I can see are :

- The switch case:
  You *should* drop in a `default`, just in case.
  Also you **ALWAYS** have to break cases. You didn't break `case 1`.

General syntax of `switch statement` :

```
switch  (x)
{
      case 1 :
             break;

      case n :
              break;

      default:
              break;
}
```

- In `PopulateRandom`:

  `int array[int M * int N]`

  should be

  `int array []`

  or

  `int *array`

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
int PrintArray2D(int M, int N){
    int array[M*N], row, column, i;

    while(row <= M && column <= N){
    for(row = 0; row <= M; row++){
        for(column = 0; column <= N; column++){
            array[i] = PopulateRandom(array[M * N]);
            printf("%d", array[i]);
            if(column == 4){
                break;
            }
        }
        column = 0;
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return array[i];
}
```

variables `row`, `column` and `i` are not initialized

```
int array[M*N], row, column, i;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

however as such they are used correspondingly in the loop

```
while(row <= M && column <= N){
```

and in this expression statement

```
array[i] = PopulateRandom(array[M * N]);
```

Also in this statement there is used name `PopulateRandom` in the function call postfix expression that was not declared yet. And moreover in this expression `array[M * N]` there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

It is not clear what this magic number 4 means in this statement

```
if(column == 4){
            ^^^
```

Also it is entirely unclear what is the meaning of this return statement with uninitialized variable `i`

```
return array[i];
```

This function declaration

```
int PopulateRandom(int array[int M * int N]){
    int i;

    while(i = 0; i < M*N; i++){
    array[i] = rand() % (M*N);
    }
    return array[i];
}
```

is invalid. You could write for example

```
int PopulateRandom(int M, int N, int array[M * N]){
//...
```

Again it is not clear the purpose of the return statement

```
return array[i];
```

that tries to return a non-existent element of the array.

In the switch statement for the label `case 1:` you should append `break` statement.

The loop can be written for example the following way

```
do
{
    printf("If you would like to search an array, enter 1 \n: ");
    //                                  ^^^ 
    printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");

    option = 0;
    scanf("%d", &option);

    switch( option )
    {
        case 1: 
        {
            printf("Enter two numbers M and N: ");                          
            scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);
            int a[M][N];
            PrintArray2D( M, N, a );
            break;
        }
    }
} while ( option != 0 );
```

The functions themselves can be written as it is shown in the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void PopulateRandom( int m, int n, int a[static const  m * n] )
{
    const int N = m * n;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) a[i] = rand() % N; 
}

void PrintArray2D( int m, int n, int a[static const m * n] )
{
    PopulateRandom( m, n, a );

    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%3d ", a[i * n + j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int m = 2;
    int n = 3;
    int a[m * n];

    PrintArray2D( m, n, a );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
  1   2   2 
  3   5   0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my first answer in this forum. Be gentle with my explications or corrections. Have a nice day !
(It's more simple of just comment prog)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
-You need to use prototype or just set function "int PopulateRandom" before "int PrintArray2D"
-Try to change your way to process at this application, it's really so complicated.
-Try to use debug for understand what is going on your program.
*/

int PrintArray2D(int M, int N){
    int array[M*N], row, column, i; // Use "static int" for row, column and i for auto init at 0, or do it manually. 

    while(row <= M && column <= N){ // Like i have said in top, you use variable but they're not initialized
    for(row = 0; row <= M; row++){
        for(column = 0; column <= N; column++){
            array[i] = PopulateRandom(array[M * N]); // use directly "array[i] = (int) rand();" for change with random value
            printf("%d", array[i]); // you can directly print a random value, you save value, but when you leave this function, your array is destroy.
            if(column == 4){
                break;
            }
        }
        column = 0;
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return array[i]; // return is useless for your usage, becaus you don't catch return value in your main. (void PrintArray2D if no return)
}

/*
-Your function need other params : int array[], int M, int N (don't forget to send M and N when you call this function)
-You need to change your algo, because this function take M and N for change just ONE element of this array.
-This function is useless in this context, check comment in "PrintArray2D" for more informations
*/
int PopulateRandom(int array[int M * int N]){
    int i;

    while(i = 0; i < M*N; i++){ // It's a FOR and not WHILE
    array[i] = rand() % (M*N);
    }
    return array[i];
}

/*
-Duplicate code isn't good, you can use printf and scanf just one time, just after your while, and set option = 1 before.
-Donc use case, but just an if, because your condition in your while check the value.
*/
int main(void){
    int option, M, N;

    printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
    printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    while(option != 0){
    switch(option){
        case 1: if(option == 1){
                printf("Enter two numbers M and N: ");                          
                scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);
                PrintArray2D(M, N);
        }
        case 0: if(option == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
    printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have comment before function, SWITCH isn't usefull, he can only use IF.
while (option != 0){
if (option == 1){

Comment: Right, my bad. I read that very early this morning and was a little bit confused! I'm going to delete my comment, as it's not useful to anyone